# MEAN Stack - Using jwt with express-restify-mongoose on only some REST methods

Tags: node.js, rest, express, jwt, restify

I'm really new to all this stuff, so please bear with me.

I try to make a REST API with the MEAN stack - To make things easy I've tried to use this:

https://github.com/florianholzapfel/express-restify-mongoose

It is working perfectly for me when I run:

*restify.serve(app, hotels);*

--> app is of course express, and hotels is my mongoose.model which points at my hotels schema.

It is also working with my 'token logic', and I can protect all the restify'd URL's with something like:

*app.use(expressJwt({ secret: 'secretkey'}).unless({path: ['/auth', '/']}));*

My problem is - how do I protect some REST methods with my token logic (POST, PUT, DELETE) on e.g '/api/hotels'
--> I wan't methods like GET to be public, but not POST, PUT and DELETE.

Is it possible?
Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

Create a middleware like this:

```
function AllCanGetIt(req, res, next) {
  if(req.method === 'GET') {
   return next();
 }

 return expressJwt({ secret: 'secretstring' })(req, res, next);
};
```

And then do:

```
 restify.serve(app, hotels, {middleware: AllCanGetIt});
```

Answer (score 2):

with "express-restify-mongoose": "^2.0.0" you should use "preMiddleware"

and then do:

```
restify.serve(app, hotels, {preMiddleware: AllCanGetIt});
```

more info:
https://florianholzapfel.github.io/express-restify-mongoose/